# app.use("/uploads/images", express.static(path.join("uploads", "images"))); This route does not work in node.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, mern

This Route below Does not work in my node.js server app API deployed in server for fetching image

```
app.use("/uploads/images", express.static(path.join("uploads", "images")));
```

On the other hand, the path below just working fine

```
app.use("/uploads", express.static('uploads'));
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong in I want the first one to categorize my images better.

In Case You want to take a look into my

App.js

```
 const fs = require("fs"); //Node Built in file Sytem module
const path = require("path"); //Path Module built in
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const express = require("express");

const placesRoutes = require("./routes/places-routes");
const usersRoutes = require("./routes/users-routes");
const bodyParse = require("body-parser");

const HttpError = require("./Models/http-error");
const { application } = require("express");
// All the Imports Above

const app = express();

// Using Middleware
app.use(bodyParse.json());



app.use("/uploads", express.static('uploads'));



app.use("/uploads/images", express.static(path.join("uploads", "images")));

//Middleware for Handling CORS Error in Frontend
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.setHeader(
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
    "Orgin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization"
  );

  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET,POST,PATCH,DELETE");
  next();
});

// Using Route attaching Middleware
app.use("/api/places", placesRoutes);
app.use("/api/users", usersRoutes);

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const err = new HttpError("This Route does not exist ", 404);

  throw err;
});
app.use((error, req, res, next) => {
  if (req.file) {
    fs.unlink(req.file.path, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }

  if (res.headerSent) {
    return next(error);
  }

  res.status(error.code || 500);
  res.json({ message: error.message || "An unknown error occupied !" });
});

mongoose
  .connect(
    `${process.env.DB_URL}`
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Database Connected");
    app.listen();
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: It depends on the folder in which the image files are located in your file system. Is that a subfolder named `images` or not?

Comment: Thanks buddy it worked all It was a lowercase Uppercase problem although I had done it a few times but it seemed like because there were two folders I got confused and renamed it again and again  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `__dirname` prefix. Instead of this:

```
app.use("/uploads/images", express.static(path.join("uploads", "images")));
```

Try this:

```
app.use(
  "/uploads/images",
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "uploads", "images"))
);
```

See my cat example image:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/node-js-express-static-path-fn8l16

*EDIT 1

[Express documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) mentions this:

> However, the path that you provide to the express.static function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process. If you run the express app from another directory, it’s safer to use the absolute path of the directory that you want to serve:

```
const path = require('path')
app.use('/static', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
```